# Laravel always returning 302 on PUT

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I created a Laravel REST API. My routes are auto-generated with `Route::apiResource()`.
Authentication is set up using Passport and is working as intended.

Now I tried to implement an Admin role with a Middleware that I attach to `store`, `update` and `delete` in my Controller:

```
$this->middleware('admin-only', ['only' => ['store', 'update', 'delete']]);
```

I want my application to respond with `403 Insufficient permissions` if the User is not an Admin.
For `GET` it is working as intended, but for PUT requests Laravel is always returning a Response with `302 Found`.

---

**AdminOnly Middleware**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminOnly {
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        $user = Auth::user();

        if (!$user->admin) {
            return Response::create('Insufficient permissions', 403);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whede does the 302 response redirect you? It should return an Location header

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo To my application root - `http:\\localhost:8000`

Comment: Apparently some other middleware redirects you before this middleware is run. Throw an exception from the constructor of "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse" class and check the stack trace - you'll see where the redirect was initiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my Error by throwing an Exception in constructor of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse` class (thanks to @jedrzej.kurylo) and examining the produced stack trace in laravels errorlog (`storage/logs/laravel.log`).
The AdminOnly middleware was never called, because I forgot to onclude the id in the request (`/person` instead of `/person/{id}`). This caused my default route to trigger and redirect to the application base.

Comment: As for me I declared the route in the wrong middleware hence there was a redirect.